# Launching another pyqt program from a currently running one

Tags: python, pyqt, window-management

I have two pyqt programs. Both should be available to run by themselves, but I need to run one of them from the other. The one that will only run manually is called `foo` and the second one (the one I want to call from `foo`) is called `bar`. I tried to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410152/pyqt-on-click-open-new-window) example and I get the new window, but with an error

> AttributeError: 'bar' object has no attribute 'exec_'

I guess I could create it, but I don't know what to put in it. So how do I make another window pop by clicking a button in the first window?

Bonus points for somebody who can make the original window inactive.

Here is how my function look right now:

```
barMaker = bar(self)
bar.exec_()
```

Unimaginative, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to just call the second gui program using

```
new_gui = subprocess.Popen("python "+path)
```

?

You can then disable your first GUI or do whatever you want with it.  The new GUI is running in a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

@ballsatballsdotballs answer did not work for me, but was very close. Referring to the docs (same for [Python2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and [Python3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor)) states:

> `subprocess.Popen(args, ...)`
>
> `args` should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in `args` if `args` is a sequence. If `args` is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent and described below.

I'm not sure if this has changed only since the original answer was posted (>4 yrs old), but for completeness, the following Popen construction worked for me:

```
new_gui = subprocess.Popen(["python", path])
```

One could also substitute "python3" if desired.