# Should I be passing GUI-entered variables between classes or restructuring program?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, pyqt4

The user enters values using line edits on the `MyWidget` screen and then presses the Enter button. This opens the `MyDialog` screen on which data will be plotted when the Run button is pressed. How can I make the line edit data accessible to `run` in `MyDialog` for plotting? Or, is there a better way of doing this which wouldn't require passing variables between classes? My program is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410152/pyqt-on-click-open-new-window) answer.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic
#  Import Qt widgets
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
    import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg \
    import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

GUI_FILE = "Minimal_UI.ui"  # GUI with line edit and 'enter' button
form_class = uic.loadUiType(GUI_FILE)[0]


class MyWidget(QtGui.QWidget, form_class):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton_Enter.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.dialogTextBrowser = MyDialog(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        # I'd like to be able to pass Temp_0 to the run method
        self.Temp_0 = self.lineEdit_Temp_0.text()
        self.dialogTextBrowser.exec_()


class MyDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.fig = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.fig)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)

        self.run_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Run')
        self.run_button.clicked.connect(self.run)
        self.stop_button = QtGui.QPushButton('Stop')
        self.stop_button.clicked.connect(self.stop)

        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        #  Widgets are stacked in the order they are added
        layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        layout.addWidget(self.run_button)
        layout.addWidget(self.stop_button)

        self.setLayout(layout)

    def run(self):
        # Create axes
        ax = self.fig.add_subplot(111)
        # Discard the old graphs
        ax.hold(False)
        # Plot data--I'd like to be able to use line edit data here
        ax.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], '*-')
        # Refresh canvas
        self.canvas.draw()

    def stop(self):
        print 'Stop Pressed'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('MyWidget')

    main = MyWidget()
    main.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MyDialog` constructor has an attribute `parent`.
With the code bellow, you create an instance of `MyDialog` with `MyWidget` as a parent:

```
self.dialogTextBrowser = MyDialog(self)
```

Two ways for a widget to access data from it's parent:

- Use the `parent` attribute in the `__init__` function

  ```
   self.lineEditData=parent.lineEdit.text()
  ```
- Use the `parent()` method anywhere

  ```
   def run(self):
       self.lineEditData=self.parent().lineEdit.text()
  ```

I say it depends on how your suppose to use the application. If your suppose to fill the lineEdit once click and get a plot, I would use the `parent` attribute or directly pass the data in the `__init__` function.
But if the user can go back to the lineEdit, change something, and click "run" again, then you should use the `parent()` method in `run`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Using the parent() method in run works. Please clarify what you mean by "use the parent attribute or directly pass the data in the __init__ function" because I haven't been able to get this to work and and according to your advice these techniques are more suitable for my application.

Comment: Me I would init `MyDialog` with `self.dialogTextBrowser = MyDialog(self.lineEdit.text(),self)`, with a constructor `__init__(self, data, parent=None)`. This way the dialog is construct specifically for "data" and can't exist without it.  But it is really just a personal preference, it just seems more logical to me. Using `parent()` is perfectly suitable too.