# PyQT: how to open new window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

First of all, similar questions have been answered before, yet I need some help with this one.

I have a window which contains one button *(Class First)* and I want on pressed, a second blank window to be appeared *(Class Second)*.

I fiddled with the code copied from this question: [PyQT on click open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14410152/pyqt-on-click-open-new-window), and I wrote this code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
import design1, design2

class Second(QtGui.QMainWindow, design2.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class First(QtGui.QMainWindow, design1.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.dialog = Second(self)

    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.dialog.exec_()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but on_pressed, this error message appears:

```
AttributeError: 'Second' object has no attribute 'exec_'
```

*(design1 and design2 have been derived from the Qt designer.)*

Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: While `QDialog` has an `exec_` method, you have subclassed `QMainWindow` which does not have that method. You might want to read up on the differences between tge classes and decide what you want to use.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here I'm using the `show` method.

Here is a working example (derived from yours):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
 
 
class Second(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
 
 
class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("click me")
 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.pushButton)
 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.dialog = Second(self)
 
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        self.dialog.show()
 
 
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If you need a new window every time you click the button, you can change the code that the dialog is created inside the `on_pushButton_clicked` method, like so:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
 
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys
 
 
class Second(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Second, self).__init__(parent)
 
 
class First(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(First, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pushButton = QtGui.QPushButton("click me")
 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.pushButton)
 
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_pushButton_clicked)
        self.dialogs = list()
 
    def on_pushButton_clicked(self):
        dialog = Second(self)
        self.dialogs.append(dialog)
        dialog.show()
 
 
def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = First()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: How can I make the third, fourth... window appear whenever I click the button ?

Comment: @Kim I exteded the example to make multiple windows appear.

Comment: How about If I wanted to open only one window and change the focus to the newly opened window so that user won't be able to make changes in the parent window?

Comment: The events for second window aren't working properly.