# opening a new window

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm starting to learn OOP using PyQt5, so I'm trying to make a window with a button and when the button is clicked, I want to show a new window. I wrote this code but it doesn't work, it just shows the window with the button, but the button doesn't do anything, it seems like it just waits, but it doesn't give me any mistakes neither

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout

class Window2(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.btn = QPushButton("Push Me")
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(self.btn)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 double window")

        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)
        self.newindow = Window2(self)

        self.show()

    def btn_clk(self):
        self.newindow.show()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
a_window = Window()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

This question guided me [PyQT: how to open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768033/pyqt-how-to-open-new-window) but it's written in PyQt4 and I'm not sure about the differences betweent these two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the answer of [PyQT: how to open new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36768033/pyqt-how-to-open-new-window) is using QMainWindow unlike you who is using QWidget.

**What is the difference between QMainWindow and QWidget?**

`QMainWindow` is a custom `QWidget` that has some flags activated, including the flag `Qt::Window`. As indicated by the [docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WindowType-enum) indicates:

> Indicates that the widget is a window, usually with a window system
>   frame and a title bar, irrespective of whether the widget has a parent
>   or not. Note that it is not possible to unset this flag if the widget
>   does not have a parent.

That is, that widget will become a window even if it has a parent widget.

So the solution is to activate this flag in Window2:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Window2(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window2, self).__init__(parent, QtCore.Qt.Window) # <---

class Window(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.init_ui()

    def init_ui(self):
        self.btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Push Me")
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.btn)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5 double window")
        self.btn.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)
        self.newindow = Window2(self)
        self.show()

    def btn_clk(self):
        self.newindow.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    a_window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Other alternative solutions are:

- Make `Window2` inherit from `QMainWindow` or `QDialog`.
- Do not pass a parent to Window2: `self.newindow = Window2()`

Comment: Thank you. So I guess in order to make the second window to act like a window I have to activate a flag saying that it is a window right? What kind of widgets could I use without having problems when I call them clicking the button? or this only happens when I treat a window like a widget?

Comment: @LissethMartínez In the code that I provide is the activation of the flag. And as I point out in the alternative solutions QDialog and QMainWindow already have that flag activated.