# pyqt: Don't lose focus on mainwindow

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I have a ctrl+f dialog and when I press the window, it causes the main window to lose focus. Is there a way to have both windows have focus?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of, but not really. Only one window can claim focus on the desktop/operating system level. You want this to be your application or main PyQT object. Then, what you want to do is define a new window type (QObject) that will be treated like a toolbox/dialog within the parent application. This will set a child-like focus attribute. Your application will retain focus on the desktop level, and now you have another inner-focus attribute for windows spawned from within your app.

[QtGui QStyleOptionToolBox](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QStyleOptionToolBox.html)

[StackOverflow: pyqt popup window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838890/python-pyqt-popup-window)