# Pop up window no longer closes when using lambda function

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyqt, pyqt4

Using the answer to this question:
[Python: PyQt Popup Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4838890/python-pyqt-popup-window)
I was able to produce a gui with a button that has a popup window.

What I would like to do now is press a button in the popup and pass a command to a function in the MyPopup class. This is easily accomplished using the lambda function, however, when you press the button in the mainwindow the popup window no longer closes and a new instance of the popup is created, resulting in two popup screens. From my understanding this is due to a signal being produced by the lambda function. Is there a way to clear this lambda function such that when the main button is pressed the old instance is closed and a new instance of the popup is loaded?

If this is not possible using lambda, is there another way to pass variables to the function to obtain the results I am looking for?

Here are some example screenshots to better illustrate my issue:

Running Script without lambda in popup

[image]

Running Script with lambda in popup

[image]

Here is the modified popup code from the previous question:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *

class MyPopup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.btn_popup = QPushButton("broken", self)
        self.btn_popup.clicked.connect(lambda state, x='lambda prevents refresh': self.function(x))

    def function(self, word):
        print('Now I dont close',word)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        dc = QPainter(self)
        dc.drawLine(0, 0, 100, 100)
        dc.drawLine(100, 0, 0, 100)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args)
        self.cw = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.cw)
        self.btn1 = QPushButton("Click me", self.cw)
        self.btn1.setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 100, 30))
        self.connect(self.btn1, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.doit)
        self.w = None

def doit(self):
    print ("Opening a new popup window...")
    self.w = MyPopup()
    self.w.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
    self.w.show()

class App(QApplication):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        QApplication.__init__(self, *args)
        self.main = MainWindow()
        self.main.show()

def main(args):
    global app
    app = App(args)
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Comment: explain yourself better, do not ever believe me 2 windows, only one that has a button and a widget painted with crossed lines.

Comment: You could publish the complete code that you use.

Comment: delete this line `self.popup = QWidget(self)`, you never use self.popup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if the lambda function does not exist the popup is destroyed, verify this by adding the following:

```
class MyPopup(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, i):
        [..]
        self.destroyed.connect(lambda: print("destroyed"))
```

in the case where there was no lambda, the message was printed, while in the other case it was not. So the solution is to destroy it manually using the `deleteLater()` method:

```
def doit(self):
    print ("Opening a new popup window...")
    if self.w:
        self.w.deleteLater()
    self.w = MyPopup()
    self.w.setGeometry(QRect(100, 100, 400, 200))
    self.w.show()
```